# React-Native pre-load uri while webview not visible

Tags: javascript, webview, react-native

I have a webview in react as follows.

```
      <WebView
        source={{ uri: this.state.url }}
        style={ this.state.style }
        javaScriptEnabled = { true }
        startInLoadingState = {true}
        onLoad = {this.showPage()}
        onLoadEnd = {this.showPage()}
      />
```

When I set this.state.url I would like the webview to load the url immediately, and then after loading onLoad or onLoadEnd calls the showPage function which shows the webview content. I cannot seem to get this to work - the webview only loads the url when it's visible in the dom. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution is to use renderLoading property of WebView. If you need to customize loader logic you can use something like this:

```
class WebScreen extends Component {
  ...
  render() {
    const { isLoading } = this.state;
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <ReactWebView
          style={styles.webview}
          source={{ uri: url }}
          onLoadStart={::this.onLoadStart}
          onLoadEnd={::this.onLoadEnd}
        />
        {isLoading && (
          <WebViewLoader style={styles.loader} />
        )}
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1
  },

  loader: {
    position: 'absolute',
    top: 0,
    right: 0,
    bottom: 0,
    left: 0,
    zIndex: 4,
    backgroundColor: 'white'
  }
});
```